# How can a constant be a random variable?

Tags: probability, random-variables

My professor posed us with the question, "Can “1” be a random variable?"
He said that we can argue both yes and no.
My argument for no is that 1 is a constant, and constants can not be a random variable. Also, there is no "randomness involved.
I was wondering if anyone could help me understand how the number 1 could be a random variable?

Comment: Take a fair $1$-cent coin and toss it. There are two possible outcomes with equal probability of occurring. Take the value of the coin to be your random variable. The coin's value will always be $1$ cent, regardless of which face turns up.

Comment: This feels like "the empty set isn't a set because it has no elements" or "the zero vector isn't a vector because it has no magnitude." If you check the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable#Definition) of a random variable, you will find that it is basically a function, and nothing in the definition prevents this function from being constant.

Comment: Of course, a random variable can be constant. It has one value with probability $1$ , that's it. Of course, in this case the intuition of an unknown value does not hold, but that does not matter since it fits to the definition of "random variable".

Answer (score 3):

Consider the function $f(x) = 7$. It's a pretty boring function! An input of $3$ gives an output of $7$, and an input of $-10$ gives an output of $7$, and so on.

Is it a *function* at all? Well, yes -- a function has one job, which is to take in inputs and return outputs. The fact that it's a *boring* function doesn't mean it's not a function, it just means that you're not going to get a Master's degree by carefully studying it.

In literally the same way, a random variable that's always $1$ is a perfectly good random variable. This is challenging, because the definition of a "random variable" is notoriously squishy in introductory probability contexts, and it's often not well-defined at all. The mathematically rigorous definition of it is that it's a measurable **function** from a particular sample space with a total measure of $1$, so the above analogy works quite well.

At an introductory level, we usually settle for something like "the outcome of a random process," or "a thing I can measure." Even with this looser definition, there's no actual requirement that the value changes upon repeated observations or anything like that; it's just a *boring* random variable.

Comment: There are the terms "non trivial random variable" and "trivial random variable", commonly used for "genuinely random random variable" and "boring random variable".

Answer (score 1):

It does fit the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable#Definition) of random variable, so it is a random variable.

But more than that: in order for "random variable" to be a useful concept, it *must* include constants.  Otherwise you would have a very hard time doing algebra with random variables, e.g. if $X$ and $Y$ are random variables you couldn't talk about $X-Y$ as a random variable without checking that this is not constant.